# NavigationManager.getInstance() returning null

Tags: android, here-api

I use the here maps api in an android application and I have a client particular client reporting difficulty using the map, I can see in the logs that the issue is `NavigationManager.getInstance()` returns null. Unfortunately I cannot replicate this locally, I can only see it on logs from client devices.

Would anyone have any advice on where I would start debugging this and what could cause this to happen ?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Please provide the following detail information to help us investigate: 1. Complete SDK Version. 2. Complete Logs. 3. Steps to reproduce the problem. 4. Please refer to this example and check if this issue is reproducible?

Answer (score -1):

NavigationManager class is responsible for providing voice and visual instructions to the user while driving or walking. An instance of NavigationManager can be retrieved using NavigationManager.getInstance(). It should be associated with a map with setMap(Map) method before navigation is started.

Navigation can be started in three different modes:
Simulation Mode - simulate(Route, long) - This mode does not require any GPS data from the device as the position is simulated along the given route.
Navigation Mode - startNavigation(Route) - This mode takes the calculated route and matches the position against the route. Before using this mode, PositioningManager is required to be running with GPS data.
Tracking Mode - startTracking() - This mode does not require a calculated route as it only tracks and shows the current position on the map.
Note: Android permission android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is required to use NavigationManager. Otherwise, the class returns Error.POSITIONING_FAILED. In addition, to ensure that the app receives location updates, the user needs to have the Location permission enabled (toggled to "on") during runtime.
The following is an example of performing navigation on a calculated route:

```js
NavigationManager navigationManager = NavigationManager.getInstance();

//set the map where the navigation will be performed
navigationManager.setMap(getMap());

// if user wants to start real navigation, submit calculated route
// for more information on calculating a route, see the "Directions" section
NavigationManager.Error error = navigationManager.startNavigation(route);
```

You can check the the [map-guidance](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/map-guidance.html) example for the same.